# why can't I get running total by group in this code?

Tags: sql, sum

I want to get running total of upvotes for all the questions. The time stamp is CreationDate, but it only returns value when the total changes.

```
Declare @UserId int;
Select @UserId = ##UserId:int##; 
With
    upvotedQuestions As (
        Select v.CreationDate,
               Sum(Count(1)*5) Over (Order By v.CreationDate) As Score
            From Posts p
                 Inner Join Votes v
                On v.PostId = p.id
            Where v.VoteTypeId = 2 -- is an upvote
              And p.PostTypeId = 1 -- is a question
              And p.OwnerUserId = @UserId
            Group By v.CreationDate
    )
Select distinct
            v.CreationDate,
            upvotedQuestions.Score As [Upvote Question]

    From Votes v
        Left Outer Join upvotedQuestions On upvotedQuestions.CreationDate =v.CreationDate
    Where v.CreationDate >= (
            Select CreationDate
                From Users
                Where id = @UserId
            )
    Order By v.CreationDate
;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would greatly clarify what you are asking about.